# Color change on scroll timeline

Tags: javascript, animation, timeline

I have a timeline and I want to change it color when the users scrolls. In order to show the progress throught the timeline.

I created the timeline with a pseudo class:

```
.timeline::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
}
```

After this I tried to create the progress with some js:

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}
```

But yet I am doing something wrong, what did I miss here

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to cut the width at 2 decimal positions. I parsed it to full Int values.
Also I added a event listener to window, I don't know if your listener works (window.onscroll).
Talking about scroll events, maybe you want to take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API which is more performant.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  console.log(scrolled);
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = parseInt(scrolled) + "%";
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', myFunction);
```

```css
body{height: 2000px; background: yellow}

#myBar{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 0%;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myBar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```